# Logit transformation of target values in regression

Tags: time-series, logistic

What sense would it make to logit transform a target variable that is a rate of something in a time series - Log(rate/1-rate). Does such a transformation have a theorethical purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what follows, I assume that the rate is bounded by 0 and 1.

This would map the rate to the log odds space, wherein the argument (rate / (1-rate)) would not be constrained to the unit interval.  This would permit using linear regression as opposed to Beta regression or logistic regression (though this benefit really only makes sense in the case where you don't have access to statistical software in my opinion).

Comment: This case is a regression problem. I could elaborate a bit. Assume I have log-transformed predictors, what would the idea be to use logit transform rate opposed to log transformed as target?